# Set textbox in given coordinates over image with autofit text for width and height of the textbox

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Set textbox in given coordinates over image with autofit text for width and height of the textbox, I tried the next code and it works fine but without autofit or to set static dimensions "width ,height" to the textbox

```
$image = Image::make(public_path('img/base-img.png'));

    $image->text($text, 670, 280, function ($font) {
        $font->file(public_path('fonts/BJadidBd.ttf'));
        $font->size(24);
        $font->color('#000000');
        $font->align('center');
        $font->valign('center');
        $font->angle(0);
    });

    $image->save(public_path('img/test.png'));
```

Comment: @suchislife help please

Comment: @dale-landry help please